# Difference between Authenticating user into my website using gmail account and googleplus account

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

I am developing a website, where users will can login using their Google account. When i was about to develop this feature i came to know about two things

1. Gmail api
2. Google+ api(social)

I want to know want is the difference between these two apis, why google is providing two different apis for authentication. I tried using google+ api, and if the user doesn't have an account in Google+ then google is forcing user to register into google plus and then login to my website.

Which one is better to use for authentication into our website google or google+?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use **Google plus Api** for authentication process then user need to have google plus account and If user is not having google plus account then He need to create it

I suggest you to use **Google api** for authentication because you can get basic information with it but if you want to get all social media data of google plus then you have to use google Api

**Simple** - API calls do not access any private user data

**Authorized** - API calls can read and write private user data, or the applications own data - API key plus OAuth 2.0 credentials (different for different application types)